# XSL-FO Region-Body background image

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have to add a background image to a page and add some text/content on the page. I am new to XSL-FO so I did some research. It looks like I need to use Region-Body and add the image using background-image attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">

  <!-- Entry point -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">

      <fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="cover-page" page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm">
          <fo:region-body background-image="url('Cover.jpg')" fox:background-image-width="29.7cm" fox:background-image-height="21cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

      </fo:layout-master-set>


      <!-- Cover Page -->
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="cover-page" force-page-count="no-force" format="i">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:call-template name="tpltCoverPage"/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>


    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Cover Page -->
  <xsl:template name="tpltCoverPage">
    <fo:block></fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The image appears as a background however it is 1700 * 1200 so the image is zoomed in and I can only see partial image in the background. Is there anyway I can zoom out the image so it fits the page height and width (without altering the actual image)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only XSL 1.1 properties, you can position a background image but you can't scale it.

FOP has extension properties for setting the width and height of a background image: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/extensions.html#backgroundimages

(AH Formatter can do that and more: https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#background)

---

Formatting just the XSL-FO from your sample worked for me with FOP 2.2:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
     xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="cover-page"
               page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm">
      <fo:region-body background-image="url('Cover.jpg')"
          fox:background-image-width="29.7cm"
          fox:background-image-height="21cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <!-- Cover Page -->
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="cover-page"
        force-page-count="no-force" format="i">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block></fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried adding background-image-width="29.7cm" and background-image-height="21cm" attributes just after background-image="url('cover.jpg')" but it does not seem to work. (sorry new to FO, do I need to add any additional files to use these extensions?)

Comment: The FOP extensions need to be in the correct namespace.  See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/extensions.html#fox-namespace.  If you add `xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"` at, e.g., the `fo:root`, then you would use the extension properties as `fox:...`.

Comment: I tried this too - I added xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions" in the root and changed to fox:background-image-height and fox:background-image-width but no luck.

Comment: What FOP version are you using? (I have no idea when the extensions were added.)  Can you add a minimal FO document sample to the question so that we can see what you currently have?

Comment: Question updated with FO document sample. Not sure how to check FOP version - is there an easy way to print version number?

Comment: `fop.bat -version` should give you the version number.